# Python request does not return email address while scraping in python3

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape email address from below URL.

```
myurl="https://www.charitychoice.co.uk/alzheimers-research-uk"
agent = {'User-Agent': 'Magic Browser'}
req1 = requests.get(myurl, headers=agent, verify=False)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(req1.content, "lxml")

for email in soup2.findAll('div', {"class": "charity-contact-details"}):
        for email1 in email.findAll('p'):
            for email2 in email1.findAll('span', {"itemprop": "email"}):
                for email3 in email2.findAll('a'):
                    email4 = email3.text
                    print(email4)
```

It does not print the email that i expected.

It works with selenium PhantomJS parser which takes long time to display email address

Please help on this with right parser to return email address instantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, but the problem is that the contents of `<span itemprop="email">` are as follows:

```
<span itemprop="email">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
{document.write(String.fromCharCode(60,97,32,104,114,101,102,61,34,109,97,105,108,116,111,58,101,110,113,117,105,114,105,101,115,64,97,108,122,104,101,105,109,101,114,115,114,101,115,101,97,114,99,104,117,107,46,111,114,103,34,32,62,101,110,113,117,105,114,105,101,115,64,97,108,122,104,101,105,109,101,114,115,114,101,115,101,97,114,99,104,117,107,46,111,114,103,60,47,97,62))}
//-->
</script>
</span>
```

In other words, the email is obfuscated to prevent spam. Nothing stopping us from parsing it, though:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.charitychoice.co.uk/alzheimers-research-uk"
agent = {"User-Agent": "Magic Browser"}
req = requests.get(url, headers=agent, verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")

for span in soup.findAll("span", {"itemprop": "email"}):
    email = "".join([chr(int(n)) for n in re.split("[^\d]", span.text) if n])

    for x in BeautifulSoup(email, "lxml").findAll("a"):
        print(x.text)
```

Output:

```
enquiries@alzheimersresearchuk.org
```

I hope this is answer is not being used for spamming, though! Also, this program makes a request and Beautiful Soup has to parse the HTML, so it's not "instant".

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works like a charm.
I got it what i expected.. You are brilliant!

Comment: Please tell me how to do that.

Comment: I did that, Thanks Ggorlen

Comment: Hi, After sometime, I ran the code again without any change. But it throws error like " NameError: email is not defined" Please help on this

Comment: I think you should kick out this `for p in div.findAll('p'):` loop from your script. It is unnecessary and without that line the script should still do the same @ggorlen.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chart2.py", line 92, in <module>
    for x in BeautifulSoup(email, "lxml").findAll('a'):
NameError: name 'email' is not defined

This is the error i am getting

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks for the updates. I left the loops mostly as-is from the OP's code. The `for p in div.findAll('p')` prevents situations where the email span is not inside a `p` and would only be relevant if the document structure changed. As for the `NameError`, are you sure the document is loaded correctly? Is it happening every time you run the script, or only occasionally? It works fine for me.

Comment: Actually, "email" is defined inside previous loop. The error is because of this second for loop defined in new line which contains "email" => for x in BeautifulSoup(email, "lxml").findAll('a'):

Comment: I didn't experience that error, and that's not something that would work once, then fail later. Python doesn't tie variables to loop scope like that. See: https://repl.it/repls/WeightyAttachedConditions. Either way, my answer was updated--try it out and let me know if you're still having trouble.

Comment: Thanks much. After your updated answer, it is running fine and the code is perfect now it seems. If any trouble come again, i will let you know. Thank you for your kind support